How do i slice an array into m groups and minimize the sum of elements of largest slice?
I want to slice an array into m groups and minimize the sum of elements of largest slice while respecting to the order of elements in array.
For example:
elements: 13.85 22.15 11.84 7.85 12.15 11.09
m: 2
answer: 13.85 22.15 | 11.84 7.85 12.15 11.09
Is this solvable with a greedy algorithm or a dynamic programming approach? Computing each possible slice seems quite expensive operation.
